# インターネットラジオのメタデータ（曲のタイトル等）を表示するコマンドラインプログラムを作りたい

Tags: linux, audio-streaming

**やりたいこと：**
インターネットラジオ局「[Digitally Imported](http://www.di.fm/)」が提供するオーディオストリーミングに含まれているはずのメタデータ（曲名等）を表示するコマンドラインプログラムを作りたいです。
現在VLCを使ってこのラジオを聴いていますが、唯一の不満としてこのメタデータを保存できないという点があるためです。そのためラジオの試聴中に自動的に曲のデータを収集し、標準出力に出して、それを好きなように別のコマンドでフィルタしたり、リダイレクトできたらと思いました。
視聴しながらメタデータを取得できるのが最高ですが、メタデータのみを取得する方法でも構わないと考えています。
プログラミング言語としては`C/C++`, `ruby`が使えます。シェルスクリプトも分かる方になってきたと思います。`Linux`のシステムコールに詳しくないため、できればC系の実装は避けたい気持ちはあります。

**現状：**

環境は`ubuntu 15.04`です。

一番手軽なのは、すでにあるコマンドラインツールで、この種のメタデータを取得できる機能を持つものを利用することであると考えましたので、[cvlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/)を使って試しました。しかしそのようなオプションが用意されているようには理解できず、コマンドラインでのVLCは諦めました。

次にVLCのAPIがあることを[ウィキペディア](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player#API)で見つけたため、それを検討してみました。
しかしながら私にはオーディオストリーミングについてほとんど知識がなく、`D-Bus`も「それ何？」というレベルでして、正直どこから手を付けていいのか分かりませんでした。

他のコマンドラインツールも数種類(cmus, pyradio)試しましたが、それらはターミナル上でGUI的な操作を提供するのが目的で、オプションも目的に適さなかったため、今のところ上手く探せておりません。

こういう状態なので、全部まるごと教えてくれとはいいません。取っ掛かりのヒントで良いので教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: クローズ票の内容を見て、質問内容を修正してみました。改善できていれば良いのですが…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

こちらの環境は Ubuntu 15.10 です。また、VLC ではなく mplayer を使っています。

例えば、[JAZZRADIO.com](http://www.jazzradio.com/) のストリーミング放送では SHOUTcast プロトコルのメタデータ形式を使用しています。

> [SHOUTcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHOUTcast)
>   SHOUTcast's streaming protocol uses metadata tags and responses that **all start with ICY**, which stands for "I Can Yell."

なので、mplayer を使うと以下の様にしてタイトルやアーティスト名を取得できます。

```sh
$ mplayer -playlist http://listen.jazzradio.com/public5/smoothjazz.pls 2>/dev/null | grep -E '^ICY Info:'
ICY Info: StreamTitle='Bennett B - In My Mind';
```

ただ、これでは使いにくいと思いますので `FIFO(named pipe)` などを使うと良いかと思います。

```sh
$ mkfifo fifo
$ mplayer -slave -playlist http://listen.jazzradio.com/public5/smoothjazz.pls >fifo 2>/dev/null &
$ grep -E '^ICY Info:' fifo
ICY Info: StreamTitle='David Lanz - The Good Life';
ICY Info: StreamTitle='Chuck Loeb - Silver Lining';
```

※ named pipe は Ruby でも使えるかと思います。

この SHOUTcast プロトコルが一般的なのかどうかは不明ですので、それぞれのストリーミング放送で使われているメタデータの送信プロトコルを調べる必要があるかと思います。

Comment: まさにこれが欲しかった答えです。ありがとうございます。また私はDigilally imported(http://www.di.fm)を聴いていたため、奇遇ですがJAZZRADIO.comも時々聴いており、非常に理解しやすかったです。mplayer で playlistオプションをつけると視聴自体はできなくなりますが、それはmplayerをslaveオプションで２つ同時に起動すれば問題なくできました。こんな感じです。`mplayer -slave http://pub1.di.fm:80..... >/dev/null 2>&1 | mplayer -slave -playlist http://pub1.di.fm:80...` あとはこれをargusさんに教わった方法で微調整すれば望み通りのことができそうです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 上記コメントの方法だと少しまずいところがあったので追記します。`mplayer`でラジオを視聴する際、このコマンドをバックグラウンド起動(&をつけての起動）すると、`mplayer`自身が停止してしまいました。コマンドオプションで避けられるかと思いましたが、上手く行かなかったです。 このためラジオの視聴自体はcvlcに任せてみたところ、上手く行きました。`cvlc [ストリーム放送のアドレス]  >/dev/null 2>&1 | mplayer -slave -playlist [ストリーム放送のアドレス]` このパイプライン自体をバックグラウンド起動すると上手く行きました。実際はパイプでつなぐ意味はなくて単に並列起動させたいからそうしているだけなのですが…